# Automatically substitute default for None in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models

**Problem**

Given a model with a field, `birthplace`, where a default is set to empty string:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    person_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    birthplace = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default="")
```

...and some code that generates instances using the following:

```py
kwargs = {
          "name": json_data.get("name"),
          "birthplace": json_data.get("birthPlace"),
         }

person = models.Person(**kwargs)
person.save()
```

I was hoping that Django would substitute the default value where the incoming `json_data.get("birthPlace")` evaluates as `None`. But I get:

> IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'birthplace' cannot be null")

**Potential Solutions**

I could use `json_data.get("birthPlace", "")`, but that seems awfully un-DRY, particularly since the "default" value is now defined in two or more places.

Alternately, I could use something like:

```py
json_data.get("birthPlace",  Person._meta.get_field_by_name('field_name').default)
```

...but it still feels awfully complex (for Python).

Am I missing a simpler, more elegant way to approach this particular issue?

Comment: @lalo a "good" example would be `{"personId":"1","name":"Steve","birthplace":"Ohio"}` whereas an example that produces that error would be `{"personId":"2","name":"Rick"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion of using

```
Person._meta.get_field_by_name('birthplace').default
```

seems ok to me.

An alternative is to check whether `birthplace` is `None`, and only include it in kwargs when it is specified. Django will use the default value when `birthplace` is not included in the kwargs.

```
kwargs = {
          "name": json_data.get("name"),
         }
birthplace = json_data.get("birthPlace")
if birthplace is not None:
    kwargs['birthplace'] = birthplace
person = models.Person(**kwargs)
```

It's a little verbose, but you don't have the duplication of the default value.

Comment: Nice approach. The actual implementation has many more fields, so I used `kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.iteritems() if v is not None}
`

Answer (score 0):

by passing `json_data.get("birthPlace")` you force None value (if birthPlace is not set or None)

I would choose one of the following

1)

```
birthplace = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True) # null=True instead of default (which makes more sence)
```

2)

```
"birthplace": json_data.get("birthPlace") or "",
```

Comment: Your first suggestion seems contrary to the recommendation to avoid using null on CharFields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null
I don't see how the second solution is different or improved from my suggestion of `json_data.get("birthPlace", "")`. Is there a difference?

Comment: Yes it's different:

>>> {'birthPlace':None}.get('birthPlace', '')
>>> print {'birthPlace':None}.get('birthPlace', '')
None
>>> print {'birthPlace':None}.get('birthPlace') or ''

Comment: Good call. In my case the data was missing a birthPlace key. But in your example, where the key is there with the value None, that is a better solution. Thanks.